# How to run multiple threads and await for complete all of them

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-ctp, c#-5.0

I want to write a method that run multiple threads and I want before end of my method I have been assured that all of them are complete using `async/await` . how I can do this?

please consider this psudo code:

```
private async void SomeWork()
{
    var a = doWork1();
    var b = doWork2();
    var c = doWork3();
    var d = doWork4();
    ...
    //I want to assure that all of above thread are complete using `C#-5` new features   
}
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirement does not match your code example: You marked your method `async`, which means that you want this method to be able to return *before* it has completed its work. Yet, you say that you want it to return only *after* all the work has been done.

Thus, if you want your method to be *synchronous*, don't use `async` and manually wait for all the tasks to complete:

```
private void SomeWork()
{
    var a = doWork1();
    var b = doWork2();
    var c = doWork3();
    var d = doWork4();
    ...
    a.Wait();
    b.Wait();
    c.Wait();
    d.Wait();
}
```

or, more elegantly:

```
    Task.WaitAll(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: `Task.WaitAll()` is a `params` method, so you can simply call it as `Task.WaitAll(a, b, c, d)`.

Answer (score 8):

The `async` way of doing this would be to make your method return a `Task` and the caller of that method would then `await` (or `Wait()`) it. Your method could then look like:

```
private async Task SomeWork()
{
    var a = doWork1();
    var b = doWork2();
    var c = doWork3();
    var d = doWork4();
    ...
    await Task.WhenAll(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void ExecuteManyTasks(int how_many)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (var i = 0; i < how_many; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Do your stuff here
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }));
        }

        // Wait for all to finish
        Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        try
        {
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch { }
    }
```